# Why doesn't "top: 0;" put the top edge of the element at the top of the screen?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to put a video element at the top of the screen, but using "top: 0;" doesn't put it at the very top, instead it makes a small border between the element and the edge of the page

```
<style>
    video {
        top: 0;
        height: 746px;
    }
</style>

    <video controls>
        <source src="wheel/wheel.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

Here's an image
[image]

Comment: `body` has default `margin: 8px` which pushes the `top: 0` eight pixels down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the browser default margin of `body`. Add `html, body { margin: 0; }`  to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Because that position is relative, try using `position: absolute` instead:

```css
video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 746px;
}
```

Comment: @RenevanderLende *Also, body as the main parent is relative by default.* --> no it's not. there is no element relative by default, all the elements are static. And if no element is positioned, the viewport will be used as reference (not the body)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, my bad, I removed the original comment.

Answer (score 0):

This way it also worked here, you define a * and put margin 0, because it will remove this border from all sides that already comes by custom, if you are going to follow the css correctly, first clean everything that is already on the page!

```
<style>
    *{
        margin: 0;
    }
    video {
        top: 0;
        height: 746px;
    }
</style>

    <video controls>
        <source src="wheel/wheel.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```